# 2 Views in a horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this view -> [image]

The view is setup basically like this

```
LinearLayout -orientation horizontal - Height (wrap)
    LinearLayout -orientation vertical - Height (wrap) - weight .65
        TextView
        RecyclerView
    LinearLayout - orientation vertical - Height (matchparent) - weight .35
        TextView
        TextView
        TextView
```

In most cases the 1st LinearLayout (the left one) would determine the size in height because the RecyclerView would usually have more than 1 entry. But in the case of the image the 1st row this logic doesn't work.  If I set the LinearLayout to the right as wrap, then when the left one is bigger then there is white around the gray background.  What is the best way to achieve  the 2nd layout is always the same height as the its parent and if the parent is too small the parent adjusts to it.

here is the full xml as requested

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".65"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_organization"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="Duke Hospital"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/availablehours"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_available_hours"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:padding="0dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:background="@color/offWhite"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_notavailable"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/darkerGreyColor"
                    android:visibility="gone"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_duration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:text="30"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="@string/abbrev_min"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_labelDuration"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/estimatedwaittime"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Could you post the XML you inflate in your RecyclerView?

Comment: @arinte you need to set height="0dp" when you declare weight property according to me

Comment: @HarshKapoor the weight is for the width

Comment: @arinte so why you didn't give the same height to other one

Answer (score 0):

You can set the minHeight of

```
LinearLayout -orientation vertical - Height (wrap) - weight .65
```

so that right side text won't get clipped

Comment: So I would need to have my code dynamically get the current height of the right element and set the minHeight on the enclosing view =-(